# waiting for data to appear/change in DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, redis

I am writing REST api which has to provide kind of real-time communication between users. Lets say I have `db.orders` collection. And I have api `GET /order/{id}`. This api should wait for some change in `order` document. For example it should return some data only when `order.status` is `ready`. I know how to do long-polling but I no idea how to check for data to appear/change in db. It would be easy if there was one app instance - then I could do this in memory, something like this:

```
var queue = []

// GET /order/{id}
function(req,res,next) {
    var data = getDataFromDb();
    if(data && data.status == 'ready') {
        res.send(data);
        return;
    }
    queue.push({id: req.params.id, req: req, res: res, next: next});
}

// POST /order/{id}
function(req,res,next) {
    req.params.data.status = 'ready'
    saveToDb(req.params.data);
    var item = findInQueue(queue,req.params.id); 
    if(item) item.res.send(req.params.data);
}
```

First handler waits for data to have status `ready` and second sets status of data to `ready`. Its just a pseudocode and many things are missing (timeout for example).

The problem is when I want to use many instances of such app - I need some messaging mechanism which will allow to communicate across instances in kind of real time.

I read about REDIS PUB/SUB but I am not sure if I can use it in this way...

I am using node.js + restify + mongoDB for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the oplog. It's a special capped collection where all operations on the database are stored. To enable them on a single server you can do.

```
mongod --dbpath=./data --oplogSize=100 --replSet test
```

then connect to the server using the console and write

```
rs.initiate()
```

use the console and do

```
use local
show collections
```

Notice the collection oplog.rs. it contains all the operations that have been applied to the server. If you are using node.js you can listen to the changes in the following way

```
var local = db.db("local");
var steam = local.collection("oplog.rs").find({}, {tailable:true, awaitdata:true}).stream();
stream.on('data', function(doc) {
});
```

for each operation on mongodb you'll receive a doc where you can establish if something you are interested in changed state.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems what I was looking for - but is it efficient? What do you think of using redis with pub/sub? I have implemented prototype with redis and it seems to work but I have no idea about its performance yet...